# How to query value from Postgresql jsonb colum

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

In a Postgres database I have a jsonb column that carries dimensions of items like the following one:

```
{
 "370730255061723346": {"volume": 3, "weight": 3200, "length": 8}, 
 "370730255061723353": {"volume": 2, "weight": 3600, "length": 9}
}
```

Since the first key is an ID, I´m struggeling with the addressing of the other information in the jsonb entry:

- How do I retrieve the number of top level entries of the jsonb (here:
  2)?
- How can I fetch the value(s) of the key "length" - and ideally
  sum them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn the JSON into a series of rows, then aggregate back. To avoid having to group the entire query, I would do the aggregation in a derived table:

```
select t.other_column, d.*
from the_table t
   cross join lateral (
      select count(*) as num_elements, 
             sum((value ->> 'length')::int) as total_length
      from jsonb_each(t.the_column) as e(id, value)
   ) as d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json functions like jsonb_each, jsonb_to_record, path extraction operators ... ie:

```
drop table if exists sample;

create temporary table sample
(
    id serial,
    dummy jsonb
);

insert into sample (dummy)
values ('{
  "370730255061723346": {
    "volume": 3,
    "weight": 3200,
    "length": 8
  },
  "370730255061723353": {
    "volume": 2,
    "weight": 3600,
    "length": 9
  }
}');

select *
from sample;

with myData as (
    select id, d.length, d.volume, d.weight
    from sample,
         lateral (select * from jsonb_each(sample.dummy)) t,
         lateral (select * from jsonb_to_record(t.value) as r(length int, volume int, weight int)) d
)
select sum(length)
from myData
where id = 1;
```